Do coupling constants change under length rescaling?
I am studying renormalization in the Skinner's notes https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/dbs26/AQFT/Wilsonchap.pdf and I can't understand the passage in formula (5.22)
$$\Gamma^{(n)}_{\Lambda}(x_{1},...,x_{n};g_{i}(\Lambda))=[\frac{Z_{\Lambda}}{Z_{s\Lambda}}]^{n/2}\Gamma^{(n)}_{s\Lambda}(x_{1},...,x_{n};g_{i}(s\Lambda))=[s^{2-d}\frac{Z_{\Lambda}}{Z_{s\Lambda}}]^{n/2}\Gamma^{(n)}_{\Lambda}(sx_{1},...,sx_{n};g_{i}(s\Lambda))$$
In particular in the last passage he says that we can evaluate the couplings at the same $s\Lambda$ after the length rescaling, but why is it true? Shouldn't be $g_{i}(\Lambda)\neq g_{i}(s\Lambda)$ generically?
